# How does window affect accuracy of skip-gram?

Tags: neural-network, word2vec, word-embedding

I would like to know how the window_size of skip-gram model affect the accuracy of predicting similar words in word embedding. Under what cases can accuracy drop and rise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While the training process tries to incrementally improve a model's relative activation for a center target word, after being input nearby words, the exact prediction accuracy is never evaluated during training, nor is a model with better accuracy necessarily "better" than one with a lower accuracy.

The training as-if you wanted to predict the center word is just a useful thing for creating sets of word-vectors with useful relative arrangements.

So for most uses of word2vec, you question isn't really relevant. You *shouldn't* pick the `window` value that leads to the best accuracy on the word2vec internal training task; you *should* pick a `window` that gives the best word-vectors for whatever downstream use you're considering.

(If for some academic/curiosity reason, you needed to know the answer to your question, you'd need to run an experiment: try many `window` values, then ask the model to predict words, and compare the accuracy. Note, though, that many word2vec implementations don't even provide an API for individual word-prediction, as that's not needed for training nor most downstream uses.)